# Eigenvalues of invariant subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, invariant-subspace

Let $V$ be a vector space over $F$ and $f:V\mapsto V$ a linear map. If $dimV=n \geq 2$ and the only invariant subspaces of $V$ are $V$ itself and {$0_V$} ,then investigate if $f$ has eigenvalues.

I'm sorry if this is a trivial question, but my book has a little to no info about invariant subspaces or even the definition of what invariant really means and what follows that.

Any little i know about it comes from wikipedia so if anyone has some site or thread(question on this site) to propose it would be great.

Comment: **Hint :** You just need the definition of "invariant subspace". Assume that $f$ has an eigenvalue, and find a (very natural) invariant subspace related to this eigenvalue. Then use the hypothesis and conclude.

Comment: @thesilverdoe Well ,it was easier than I thought .I concluded that f has eigenvalues. Thank you a lot .

Comment: Apparently, you assumed that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $f$, and you deduced from it that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $f$. What's the point?

Comment: @anotheruser you are absolutely right...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ has some eigenvalue $\lambda$, let $v$ in $V\setminus\{0\}$ be such that $f(v)=\lambda v$. Then, for each $\mu\in F$,$$f(\mu v)=\mu f(v)=\,u\lambda v=\lambda(\mu v).$$So, $Fv$ is a one dimensional invariant subspace of $V$. But it is being assumed that $V$ has invariant subspaces other than $V$ or $\{0_V\}$, and $Fv$ is none of them.

Comment: I don't get how a linear map  of a vector spave that maps to itself  can have no eigenvalues. Don't all square matrices have eigenvalues in $\mathbb{C}$ by fundumental theorem of algebra ?

Comment: *Where* did you mention $\Bbb C$ in your question? Isn't this a question about vector spaces over fields in general?

Comment: Yes it is in general. But $\mathbb{C}$ is pretty huge and i can't  think of any field F that is not a subset of $\mathbb{C}$ other than $\mathbb{Z}_p$ ,p be a prime.

Comment: Nevermind i was thinking the wrong way , you are 100% correct .Thank you for your time !For example if $\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
 -1& 0 \\
\end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{3 \times 3}$ has no eigenvalues, since its characteristic polynomial is $f(x)=x^2+1$.